# Any alternative to using delegation in passing data to the UI from the ViewModel in iOS?

Tags: ios, mvvm, swift4, rx-swift

I've created some *very basic data bindings* with variables between my VC and VM using RxSwift (which I've very new to), and am now perplexed as to how best communicate other UI actions from the VM that need additional data passed along with them.

Such as trigger popup alerts for error message passing, navigation controls, etc. as I want to send parameters along with them.

I've thought about using delegation again.  But would it be inappropriate to mix bindings and delegation together in the same VM?

I'd like to abstract a pattern that can template to other MVVM areas of the app that would need to do the same thing for each VC/VM mix.

Comment: There are many procedures to achieve this and more or less all are best for a specific situation. Using MVVM procedure you should explain exactly what you are doing and why. But in my opinion already using Rx in iOS Swift is a complete fail. You will receive answers which will be opinion-based. Probably all of them will work but each of them will create a mess in your project. So I guess just go with any you want.

Comment: Disclaimer: I have no experience with Reactive Programming. I'm reading a lot about this as well, and came across an article that shows how to use closure properties: https://blog.lickability.com/our-view-on-view-models-4bb1d0675038 (look under the Delegating Action section).

Comment: Any closure from the VC sent to the viewModel breaks the SOC (Separation of Concerns) principle as the closure(s) now become part of the viewModel layer.  The viewModel layer should not be responsible with any *strong* handlers to the VC.

Comment: @SebastianDwornik: in the link I shared the closure is sent from the View and handled by the VC; the VM is not involved.

Answer (score 0):

This can easily turn into an opinion based question, but if you want to stick with RxSwift, and I assume you do, the best way is to create subscriptions from the VC to VM. In essence, your VM would subscribe to a `Variable`, `PublishSubject` or similar in the VC and you would handle those where necessary.

For example of something like this using Strings as data:

```
let subject = PublishSubject<String>()

// As you can see the subject casts nicely, because it's an Observable subclass
let observable : Observable<String> = subject

observable
    .subscribe(onNext: { text in
        print(text)
    })
    .addDisposableTo(disposeBag)

// You can call onNext any time you want to emit a new item in the sequence
subject.onNext("Hey!")
subject.onNext("I'm back!")
```

You can have a look at more examples here:
http://swiftpearls.com/RxSwift-for-dummies-3-Subjects.html